# How to make Stickable TabView in ScrollView with ViewPager in react native?

Tags: android, react-native, user-interface

I am making twitter profile like screen..
UI Tree is

```
<ScrollView>
   <Tabs>
    ...
   </Tabs>
   <ViewPager>
     <View>
      <FlatList/>
     </View>

     <View>
      <FlatList/>
     </View>
   </ViewPager>

</ScrollView>
```

[I want something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MpMKV.jpg)